# Asp.Net MVC Layout reload just RenderBody() when navigating thru menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have Layout with navigation menu, when I click menu - whole page reloaded. How to reload just Views in RenderBody() section? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You will need learn about SPA applications. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: this Link Help [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035944/how-to-reaload-only-content-page-without-reloading-treemenu) use javascrupt Or Ajax to call Partial View

Answer (score 0):

RenderBody() will load the current view into that portion of the page.  When you click on the link in the layout, however, the page reloads.  You should change their code so that when you click on the tab it calls a function which reloads the page and puts the content of the page where the RenderBody() is.